# Spring Boot + Angular project structure and architecture

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, maven, architecture

I am building an application which consists of a spring boot backend and an angular frontend.
Which advantages and disadvantages do the following project structures have?

Requirements:

- maven project
- spring security (login + registration) -> form? basic? jwt?
- Angular frontend
- Spring Boot Backend

I thought of following possibilities:

### Angular inside spring project running on same server

The Angular project folder is inside the spring boot project. When building the spring boot application the angular project is built and included inside the static folder.

Advantages:

- only one deployable
- easy use of spring security (form login + sessions)
- single code base

Disadvantages:

- ui is highly dependent on backend
- load balancing could be more difficult (I am not sure about this)

### Spring Boot + Angular in one project and same server

The angular app and spring boot app are in separate folders (maybe a root project including these 2 maven modules). When building the spring project the angular project is built and included in it's target folder (something like: https://github.com/FraktonDevelopers/spring-boot-angular-maven-build)

Advantages:

- only one deployable
- easy use of spring security (form login + sessions)
- single code base
- multi module maven project

Disadvantages:

- ui is highly dependent on backend
- load balancing could be more difficult (I am not sure about this)

### Spring Boot + Angular in one project and different servers

The Angular project folder is in in the same project as the spring boot project (maybe one root folder and inside it there is the ui and the backend project as separate folders). The backend and the ui are running on separate servers (angular is not included in the jar/war of spring boot)

Advantages:

- single code base
- decoupled ui from backend
  Disadvantages:
- security is much more difficult (you need to do check if users are logged in manually in the frontend and receive the session/jwt manually)

### Spring Boot + Angular in different projects and different servers

The two projects are completely separated (two git repos) and have no code in common. They are deployed on different servers.

Advantages:

- decoupled ui from backend
  Disadvantages:
- security is much more difficult (you need to do check if users are logged in manually in the frontend and receive the session/jwt manually)
- you have to open two projects when developing

**Which project structure is "best practice"? Are there other alternatives? dit I miss any advantages/disadvantages?**

Are there any example projects / open source projects? I would prefere architectures/structures which are production ready and preferably they include spring security.

Answer (score 1):

**Security**

The "easy use of spring security" might not be as easy as you think. In particular, the "form-login and session" part won't work out of the box:

When a client sends a request without valid (or expired) credentials, Spring Security will intercept that, and instead respond with the login form. That's nice if the request was a page navigation in the browser, but what if the invalid request hits the API endpoint? The angular service that issued the XMLHttpRequest won't know what to do with this unexpected HTML document.

Also, sessions? I for one find session expiration to be really annoying from a usability perspective, and with Angular, application state can be easily held in the browser, allowing us to get rid of server side sessions (which also nicely prevents CSRF attacks, which your API might otherwise be vulnerable to, simplifies load balancing, and improves the scalability of the backend).

So while Spring Security can help with access control, it can't solve the login part, and therefore does not benefit from having the UI served by the same server.

**Other considerations**

It is worth noting that "togetherness" during development and runtime can be decided independently.

For development, I would consider:

- Might I ever want to use the backend in a different frontend?
- Will the same person do front and backend changes, or will these be done by different people, possibly at different times? Will these changes be released together or separately?
- What is my testing strategy? Will front- and backend be tested in isolation or together?

So if I have a bunch of full stack developers, each of which will implement their feature across all layers, to be released and tested together, everything would go into the same repository and build (though I would still retain the ability to build the frontend separately during development: no need to wait for a spring boot restart when I change my angular code).

In contrast, if I have a separate frontend and backend team, whose releases might get out of sync, and who test separately, I'd create separate repositories and builds.

For runtime, I would consider:

- ease of deployment: Is it easier to deploy together or separately in whatever place I wish to deploy to?

That's pretty much the only consideration. In particular, there should be no coupling beyond the HTTP API, because such coupling confers no benefits and inhibits the future evolution of the system: if ops preferences or best practices change, I want to be able to respond to that. For instance, if I later want to use a CDN for my UI, I should be able to do that easily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As for the security part: which authentication type would you chose? I read this guide: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/ and I am still not sure which type I would use when I just have 1 backend and 1 frontend with normal login/signup.

Comment: "... and build (though I would still retain the ability to build the frontend separately during development: no need to wait for a spring boot restart when I change my angular code)." So you would run angular in its own webserver or would you pack it into the spring's one and let angular additinally be able to run in it's own server? As for your considerations: I just have a full stack team which do front and backend. And there will be no second UI for the application.

Comment: Is there any template project on github or open source project on github you would recommend to learn from?

Comment: 1) Sorry, that link is way too verbose for me to read through ... 2) The angular CLI comes with its own development webserver with live code reload. I meant to say that you'll want to use that, rather than doing maven builds all the time. 3) It's been a while since I did a "normal" login (we outsourced identity management to a different component such as Google Login using OpenID Connect, implemented by angular-oauth2-oidc and spring security), so I can not recommend libraries or template projects for your usecase.